# Firefox Web Developer Tools - How can I change the default debugger shortcuts?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

I recently got some issues with Firebug and I'm trying to use the built-in Firefox web developer tools instead.

My main issue for now is that I don't see how to change the debugger's shorcuts : `run (F8)` / `Step Over (F10)` / `Step In (F11)` and `Step Out (Shift+F11)`.

I did try with [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/) and [that](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension) extensions but without success.

I want them to be : `run (F9)` / `Step Over (F8)` / `Step In (F7)` and `Step Out (F10)`.

Any idea?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do this without creating a specific extension for this.