# Change firefox developer tools debugger key bindings

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-developer-tools

How can you change the firefox debugger's step in, step over, step out key bindings?

Couldn't find any docs on this nor anything in about:config.

Comment: Unfortunately there are some persistent bad bugs in the Firefox debugger - [step not working](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=977972), [high cpu](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1003664) etc. While Firefox's devtools are better than most, I personally use Chome/Chromium for stepping through JS.

Comment: I personally find chrome's inability to have it's ui customized, even basic things like turning off animations, much more annoying than occasional debugger bugs.

Comment: Yeah, Chrome is also generally slower and freezes up everything more than Firefox - but debugging is the one thing it's great at.

Comment: Kind of ancillary to the question...

Comment: Unanswered duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984214/firefox-web-developer-tools-how-can-i-change-the-default-debugger-shortcuts?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone...

This solution only works on Windows though, since it's a [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) script.

It changes the keys so:

`F7`  -> "Step in"
`F8`  -> "Step over"
`F9`  -> "Run"
`F10` -> "Step out"

```
#WinActivateForce
#InstallKeybdHook
#Persistent
#HotkeyInterval,100
#NoEnv
SetKeyDelay, –1
SendMode Input

$F7:: 
{
    if WinActive("ahk_classMozillaWindowClass")
    {  
        Send {F11}
        Return
    }
    Send {F7}
    Return
}

$F8:: 
{
    if WinActive("ahk_classMozillaWindowClass")
    {  
        Send {F10}
        Return
    }
    Send {F8}
    Return
}

$F9:: 
{
    if WinActive("ahk_classMozillaWindowClass")
    {  
        Send {F8}
        Return
    }
    Send {F9}
    Return
}

$F10:: 
{
    if WinActive("ahk_classMozillaWindowClass")
    {  
        Send {Shift down}{F11}{Shift up}
        Return
    }
    Send {F10}
    Return
}
```

I'm pretty sure this can be improved (I'm not an Autohotkey expert). For example, the `F7`, `F8`, `F9` and `F10` keys will be changed *everywhere* in Firefox, not simply when you're debugging!

I'm interested if someone has improvements to suggest.